# live each jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table style="width: 50%" id="myTable">
 <tbody>
 <tr><td>Row 1</td><td>dd</td><td>red</td><td>dd</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row 2</td><td>dd</td><td>green</td><td>dd</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row 3</td><td>dd</td><td>red</td><td>dd</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" name="addRow">Add Row</a>

$(document).ready(function () {        
       $("a[name=addRow]").click(function() {
                $("table#myTable tr:last").after('<tr><td>Row 4</td><td>dd</td><td>red</td><td>dd</td></tr>');
                return false;
        });

    $('#myTable tbody tr td').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).text() == 'red')
    {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else if ($(this).text() == 'green')
    {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});

 });
```

why if i add new rows then this doesnt work? i try add live:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr td').live('each', function()
```

but this also doesnt work

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/pytP2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {        

$("a[name=addRow]").click(function() {
    $("table#myTable tr:last").after('<tr><td>Row 4</td><td>dd</td><td>red</td><td>dd</td></tr>');
    initRow($("table#myTable tr:last"));
    return false;
});

$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function()
{
    initRow($(this));
});

function initRow(row)
{
    row.find('td').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var textInTD = $.trim(self.text());
        if (textInTD == 'red')
        {
            row.css('background-color', 'red');
            return false;
        }
        else if (textInTD == 'green')
        {
            row.css('background-color', 'green');
            return false;
        }
    })
}
});
```

If you need, I can add comments to the code.

Answer (score 1):

`live` will attach a handler to a specific event for all existing and future instances of the specified elements, which is different to what you're trying to do, as you need to update the styling of new elements added to the table. `live` would only be useful if you wanted to add say a 'click' event to each new row in your table.

To fix your code you need to call the style update function after each new element is added, there's a working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/zDvAQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

`live` takes an event type (such as `'click'`) as a first parameter. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Did you read the manual for `live`? It's not a function that runs the handler every time an element is created - rather, it runs the handler every time the specified event is fired on any element that matches the query now or will match in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the onload code is only fired once: on load...

If you want the code to be executed after adding a new row, extract the wanted code into a new function and call it after adding the new rows

if you're worried about performance (if the table can get very big) you could also pass the new row to the function.